# IE8 in Windows XP vs Windows 7 pulls different security certificate.

Tags: apache, security, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

I am having a strange problem. When you view one of our websites under IE8 XP it pulls the wrong security certificate from the server.

When I view the same website in IE8 on Windows 7 it pulls the correct security certificate.

Same exact url: https://aframe.insurancehelper.com/

I am not sure how to debug this. Does XP identify itself differently than Win7 and every other OS?

Let me know if I can supply any additional information that would be helpful.

The sever is using Apache 2.2.

[image: IE8 Under XP]
[image: IE8 Under Win7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely caused by using multiple SSLs on one IP via Apache. From what I've seen the only way to overcome this is via a unique IP per SSL. More detail can be found below.

This is only an issue for IE in XP too. If you're willing to ignore that minor segment of users you could continue as normal, place a warning on the site that IE8 and below users, that they should switch to a more up to date and secure browser.

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm